# How do I get the current UTC offset (time zone)?

Tags: c++, boost-date-time

How do I get the current UTC offset (as in time zone, but just the UTC offset of the current moment)?

I need an answer like "+02:00".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There are two parts to this question:

1. Get the UTC offset as a `boost::posix_time::time_duration`
2. Format the `time_duration` as specified

---

Apparently, getting the local time zone is not exposed very well in a widely implemented API. We can, however, get it by taking the difference of a moment relative to UTC and the same moment relative to the current time zone, like this:

```
boost::posix_time::time_duration get_utc_offset() {
    using namespace boost::posix_time;

    // boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor uses the C-API to adjust a
    // moment given in utc to the same moment in the local time zone.
    typedef boost::date_time::c_local_adjustor<ptime> local_adj;

    const ptime utc_now = second_clock::universal_time();
    const ptime now = local_adj::utc_to_local(utc_now);

    return now - utc_now;
}
```

---

Formatting the offset as specified is just a matter of imbuing the right `time_facet`:

```
std::string get_utc_offset_string() {
    std::stringstream out;

    using namespace boost::posix_time;
    time_facet* tf = new time_facet();
    tf->time_duration_format("%+%H:%M");
    out.imbue(std::locale(out.getloc(), tf));

    out << get_utc_offset();

    return out.str();
}
```

Now, `get_utc_offset_string()` will yield the desired result.

Comment: It's a complicated issue; a specific UTC offset may correspond to multiple timezones, for example.

Comment: @Roger: So... I guess the correct way to say it is that I am looking for the UTC offset for the current time, not the time zone?

Comment: Yes, if that's what you're interested in (which is also what it sounds like to me), this answer is spot on.  I was responding more to "getting the local time zone is not exposed very well in a widely implemented API."  Just be aware that the UTC offset you get for today could be different later (or earlier).

Comment: @Roger: I updated my question to be more precise. Of course, your comment still stands with regards to "getting the local time zone..." :)

Answer (score 4):

Since C++11 you can use chrono and [std::put_time](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/put_time):

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iomanip>
#include <iostream>
int main ()
{

  using sc = std::chrono::system_clock;
  auto tm = sc::to_time_t(sc::now());

  std::cout << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tm), "formatted time: %Y-%m-%dT%X%z\n");

  std::cout << "just the offset: " << std::put_time(std::localtime(&tm), "%z\n");

}
```

This produces the following output:

> formatted time: 2018-02-15T10:25:27+0100
>
> just the offset: +0100