# how to get utc offset in linux using c++

Tags: c++, debian, utc

I was using following code segment to calculate utc offset, but I realize sometimes it's returning wrong results:

```
double DateTime::getUTCOffset()
{
    time_t currtime;

    struct tm * timeinfo;



    time ( &currtime );

    timeinfo = gmtime ( &currtime );

    time_t utc = mktime( timeinfo );

    timeinfo = localtime ( &currtime );

    time_t local = mktime( timeinfo );



    // Get offset in hours from UTC

    double offsetFromUTC = ((difftime(local, utc) / HOUR_IN_SECONDS) );

    // Adjust for DST

    if (timeinfo->tm_isdst)
    {
        offsetFromUTC += 1;
    }
    return offsetFromUTC;
}
```

%90 of the time it's correct though, what's the best way of calculating utc offset?

Comment: Related: How to get the UTC offset with Boost DateTime: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3854496/how-do-i-get-the-current-utc-offset-time-zone

Answer (score 7):

I think the `tm_gmtoff` field should be available on you system.

```
std::time_t current_time;
std::time(&current_time);
struct std::tm *timeinfo = std::localtime(&current_time);
long offset = timeinfo->tm_gmtoff;
```